# .ASP Site migration from Server 2003 to 2008 R2 Database Issues

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7, migration

Currently migrating some ASP sites from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2. I have narrowed the issue down to this piece of code:

```
set statconn = server.createobject("ADODB.connection")

statconn.open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; DATA SOURCE=" & server.mappath("/database/VFEStats.mdb")
Set rsStats = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

rsStats.open "select SiteID, StatIP, StatPageViewed, StatRefererPage, StatBrowser, StatUniqueUser, StatQS from WebStats", statconn,2,2,1
rsStats.addnew
rsStats("SiteID") = intSIteID
rsStats("StatIP") = request.servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
rsStats("StatPageViewed") = request.servervariables("PATH_INFO")
rsStats("StatRefererPage") = request.servervariables("HTTP_REFERER")
rsStats("StatBrowser") = request.servervariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
rsStats("StatUniqueUser") = request.servervariables("LOCAL_ADDR")
rsStats("StatQS") = request.servervariables("QUERY_STRING")
rsStats.update
rsStats.close

set rsStats = nothing
statconn.close
set statconn = nothing
```

I don't believe that I have to set it to run in 32-bit mode in IIS7, because Microsoft.ACE is a 64-bit program. I am getting the following error log:

```
GET / |9|800a0cb3|Current_Recordset_does_not_support_updating._This_may_be_a_limitation_of_the_provider__or_of_the_selected_locktype.
```

I think that the issue has to do with the numbers appended to rsStats.open ...,2,2,1 line of code.

I think I simply have to modify this code to be compatible with the new server.